# Floated image and text to the right

Tags: css

I'm a newbie to CSS to please forgive me, I've spent ages on this:

I have an image which I want floated left with a width of 40% and margin-right of 40px. I then have a div with a caption in it that I want to position to the right of the image. This works on my Mac, but is it cross browser compatible?

HTML

```
    <img ... >
    <div class="right_column">some text</div>
```

CSS

```
    img { float:left; width:40%; margin-right:40px; }
```

The text in the right_column div sits to the right of the image, with the margin between the two. It seems too easy to be true?

Comment: It is so easy, yes.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. `float` is used for wrapping images and text.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that a div will by default take up all available horizontal space. So in this case the floated left image is taking up 40% and the right hand div will take up the remaining space (minus the margin). I don't have to apply a float-right or a float-left or an overflow hidden, or a width auto to the right hand div – it just works without any CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property `display: inline-block` with the image and `div.right_column` to get the same result, like this:

CSS:

```
img{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.right_column{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

here the fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/56ap36q8/

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the float property is cross-browser compatible.

> In its simplest use, the `float` property can be used to wrap text around images.

You can read more about float [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

I recommend installing multiple browsers to test on if you're going to be learning web development. This way you can see for  yourself what works on each browser.
Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari seem to be the most popular if you're on a Mac.